# Retornar último colaborador que verificou o carro

Tags: mysql

Pretendo retornar o último colaborador que verificou o carro de produtos antes do que está actualmente a verificar.

O carro tem de ser o mesmo e só no caso de ter algum produto verificado no carro como **`Não OK`**.

Query:

```
SELECT nome, DATE(C.DataRegisto4) AS Data, CarrosAla.Descricao, 
ListagemPrduto.Descricao, C.Sim, C.DataP, C.Stock, C.Obsevacao3,
(SELECT Colaborador FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios AS B
ON B.id = A.Colaborador WHERE A.IdCarro = C.IdCarro ORDER BY A.Id DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS `Colaborador Anterior`
WHERE (C.Sim = 'Não Ok' OR C.DataP = 'Não Ok')  AND Colaborador = '33'
AND DATE(C.DataRegisto4) = '2019-08-12'
```

O problema está nesta parte da query:

```
(SELECT Colaborador FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios AS B
ON B.id = A.Colaborador WHERE A.IdCarro = C.IdCarro ORDER BY A.Id DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS `Colaborador Anterior`
```

Aqui pretendo retornar o último colaborador que verificou o carro, mas neste momento retorna o colaborador que está a verificar no momento.

Deixo o exemplo com as tabelas com que estou a criar a query:

[Exemplo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3668t3hptyMCWdjgKDrQDi/0)

Na coluna **`Colaborador Anterior`** devia retornar o colaborador 27, mas está a retornar o 33, que foi o último que verificou o carro.

Comment: Consegue simular, nesse seu exemplo, uma tabela com o resultado que você espera?

Comment: Outra coisa: Qual a versão do `MySQL` que você está utilizando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do `MySQL 8.0` você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

- Adicionar uma coluna incremental para vincular os eventos de acordo com o histórico. Para fazer isso utilizar a função [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx) vinculando as colunas `IdCarro` e `IdProduto` e ordenando pela coluna `DataRegisto4` em ordem descrescente faciltando a identificação do último registro no histórico, que irá possuir a ordem `1`:

  ```
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rlc.IdCarro, rlcIdProduto ORDER BY rlc.DataRegisto4 DESC) AS ordem
  ```
- Utilizar a cláusula [`WITH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) para armazenar a informação anterior, facilitando o vínculo com os registros de outras verificações:

  ```
  WITH historico AS (
    SELECT rlc.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rlc.IdCarro, IdProduto ORDER BY rlc.DataRegisto4 DESC) AS ordem
      FROM RegistoListagemCarros rlc
  )
  ```
- Realizar o vínculo com um `LEFT JOIN` (para garantir que, caso não exista registro anterior, o evento ainda será mostrado) na `CTE` `historico` vinculando pelas colunas  `IdCarro` e `IdProduto` e com a `ordem + 1` garantindo que será o próximo registro do histórico que, de acordo com o que foi explicado anteriormente, terá a próxima ordem:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN historico h2
    ON h2.IdCarro = h.IdCarro
   AND h2.IdProduto = h.IdProduto
   AND h2.ordem = h.ordem + 1
  ```
- No `WHERE` o filtro deve ser feito pela `ordem = 1` garantindo que o último evento será verificado:

  ```
  WHERE h.ordem = 1
  ```

A query completa ficaria parecida com a seguinte:

```
WITH historico AS (
  SELECT rlc.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rlc.IdCarro, rlc.IdProduto ORDER BY rlc.DataRegisto4 DESC) AS ordem
    FROM RegistoListagemCarros rlc
)
SELECT u.nome,
       h.DataRegisto4 AS data,
       ca.Descricao1,
       lp.Descricao,
       h.Sim,
       h.DataP,
       h.Stock,
       h.Obsevacao3,
       h2.id AS idAnterior,
       u2.nome AS colaboradorAnterior
  FROM historico h
  LEFT JOIN historico h2
    ON h2.IdCarro = h.IdCarro
   AND h2.IdProduto = h.IdProduto
   AND h2.ordem = h.ordem + 1
  LEFT JOIN usuarios u2
    ON u2.id = h2.Colaborador
 INNER JOIN ListagemPrduto lp
    ON lp.Id = h.IdProduto
 INNER JOIN CarrosAla ca
    ON ca.Id = h.IdCarro
 INNER JOIN usuarios u
    ON u.id = h.Colaborador
 WHERE h.ordem = 1
   AND (h.Sim = 'Não Ok' OR h.DataP = 'Não Ok');
```

Que resulta em:

```
| nome   | data                | Sim    | DataP | Stock | Obsevacao3 | Descricao1 | Descricao | idAnterior | colaboradorAnterior |
| ------ | ------------------- | ------ | ----- | ----- | ---------- | ---------- | --------- | ---------- | ------------------- |
| Teste1 | 2019-08-13 14:58:45 | Não OK | OK    | OK    | Teste      | G3 Ala A   | Teste11   | 323        | Teste               |
| Teste1 | 2019-08-13 14:58:45 | Não OK | OK    | OK    | Teste      | G3 Ala A   | Teste16   | 327        | Teste               |
| Teste1 | 2019-08-13 14:58:45 | Não OK | OK    | OK    | Teste      | G3 Ala A   | Teste21   | 332        | Teste               |
```

---

Você pode ver a `query` funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3668t3hptyMCWdjgKDrQDi/2).

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Numera a saída de um conjunto de resultados. Mais especificamente, retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 na primeira linha de cada partição.

Answer (score 2):

Montei uma *query* porém, talvez seja necessário fazer algumas validações para ver se funciona em todos cenários.

Não me ficou claro uma coisa, se o colaborador 33 verificar o carro 3 vezes, teoricamente ele foi o ultimo a verificar, entretanto eu adicionei duas opções na *query* e você pode decidir o que precisa para o negócio.

```
SELECT 
    nome, 
    DATE(C.DataRegisto4) AS Data, 
    Descricao1, 
    Descricao, 
    C.Sim, 
    C.DataP, 
    C.Stock, 
    C.Obsevacao3,
    (SELECT Colaborador FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios AS B ON B.id = A.Colaborador 
            WHERE A.ID <> C.Id AND Colaborador <> '33' order by A.DataRegisto4 desc LIMIT 1,1) AS `Colaborador Anterior`,
    (SELECT A.ID FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios AS B ON B.id = A.Colaborador 
            WHERE A.ID <> C.Id AND Colaborador <> '33' order by A.DataRegisto4 desc LIMIT 1,1) AS `ID Item Anterior`  ,     

    (SELECT Colaborador FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios AS B ON B.id = A.Colaborador 
            WHERE A.ID <> C.Id  order by A.DataRegisto4 desc LIMIT 1,1) AS `Colaborador Anterior 2`,
    (SELECT A.ID FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios AS B ON B.id = A.Colaborador 
            WHERE A.ID <> C.Id order by A.DataRegisto4 desc LIMIT 1,1) AS `ID Item Anterior 2`               
FROM RegistoListagemCarros AS C 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ListagemPrduto  ON ListagemPrduto.Id    = C.IdProduto
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CarrosAla       ON CarrosAla.Id         = C.IdCarro
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios        ON usuarios.id          = C.Colaborador
WHERE 1=1
    AND (C.Sim = 'Não Ok' OR C.DataP = 'Não Ok') 
    AND Colaborador = '33' 
    AND DATE(C.DataRegisto4) = '2019-08-13'
```

**O que foi feito?**

Selecionado os dados ordenando pela data e no *where* foi removido o item atual. Se quiser verificar o ultimo colaborador(não considerando o atual), ele pega o ultimo registro que não é do colaborador

Answer (score 1):

Bruno acrescenta o Id do Produto, assim:

```
ON B.id = A.Colaborador WHERE A.IdCarro = C.IdCarro AND A.IdProduto = C.IdProduto ORDER BY A.Id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
```